# Can't get MAAS nodes to enlist

Tags: vmware, maas

I'm having an issue very similar to this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/517684/maas-add-node-failing

I've been banging my head against the wall for days. I'm running VMWare ESXi 5.5 and Ubuntu 14.04.1.  I have a maas controller setup (VM) and it has two interfaces. Eth0 can see my LAN network and the Internet and eth1 is a private VM-only network for MAAS.  I created a second VM node but I can't get it to enlist.

PXE booting is working. The node boots via PXE and gets an IP on the MAAS private network, but it hangs with the message mentioned in the post I linked to:

```
util.py[WARNING]:  Failed accessing user data.
```

I've also tried booting from the CD and entering in the IP of the MAAS controller. The machine immediately shuts down, but never enlists.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.  Finally figured this out.  For some reason, I had the MAAS Cluster Controller API URL set to my LAN network address, not my MAAS internal network address.

I fixed this by running

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
```

Then I set the API URL to:

```
http://192.168.xxx.xxx/MAAS
```

And now my PXE nodes enlist properly!

Hope that helps someone out.